# ¿Se puede obtener la ruta y extensión de las fuentes instaladas en c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando obtener la extensión de una font (.ttf, .otf) en C#. Pero parece que este código no funciona:

```
if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)

                {
                   MessageBox.Show(fontDialog1.Font.ToString());
        
                    string ruta = Path.GetFileName(fontDialog1.Font.Name);
                    MessageBox.Show(ruta);
                    lblDescripcion.Text = fontDialog1.Font.Name;
                    lblTamanio.Text = Math.Round(fontDialog1.Font.Size).ToString();
                    if (lblDescripcion.Text.Length > 20)
                        lblDescripcion.Text = lblDescripcion.Text.Substring(0, 20);
                    lblEstilo.Text = fontDialog1.Font.Style.ToString();
                    txtFontTotal.Text = lblDescripcion.Text + "," + lblTamanio.Text + "," + lblEstilo.Text;
                }
```

¿Es posible obtener, por ejemplo, ALGER.TTF, en lugar de Algerian Normal?

Comment: Qué significa, exactamente, "este código no funciona"? Cuál es el error? Qué es lo que obtienes? La respuesta a tu pregunta es "Sí", muy probablemente, pero a como está no es tan fácil responder.

Comment: Hola Arriel. Me refiero a que con ese código, aunque no produce error, no obtengo el nombre del archivo y la extensión de la fuente. Por ejemplo, yo quiero obtener alger.TTF, en lugar de Algerian Normal, para obtener la extensión del archivo font.

Comment: El comentario a cerca de tu problema agregalo en la pregunta, con una mejor description de tu resultado actual y el esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer no se puede conseguir de la forma en que lo estás intentando. La propiedad `Name` de la clase `Font` no hace referencia al nombre de archivo sino al nombre público de la definición de la fuente.

La información de las que están instaladas en el sistema *Windows* la guarda en el *Registry*, aunque no está siempre en el mismo lugar, depende de la versión.

La llave del *registry* donde está esa información en Windows 10 es:
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`. Contiene pares *nombre*-*valor*. Puedes intentar utilizar el nombre de la fuente para encontrar la entrada que le corresponde.

Los nombres de archivo que están ahí no tienen todos la ruta completa, tendrás que completarla teniendo en cuenta que los archivos de las fuentes están en la carpeta `C:\Windows\Fonts`, si estás en el explorador puedes ir directo mediante `%WINDIR%/Fonts`.

Es posible que algunas fuentes no las puedas encontrar. Pasa con algunas de Office y de otros programas.

Comment: De acuerdo. Muchas gracias